# Create a new SQL Server Reporting Services service application (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, project-server, service-application

I'm looking for how to create a new SQL Server Reporting Services service application only with PowerShell.

So here is my script:

```
$Service=New-SPRSServiceApplication -Name "ReportingServicePool" -ApplicationPool ReportingServicesServicePool -DatabaseName "ReportingServiceProjectServer" -DatabaseServer " DBTest"
$Proxy=New-SPRSServiceApplicationProxy -Name "Reporting Services Application Proxy" -ServiceApplication $Service 
Get-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup -default | Add-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroupMember -Member $proxy
```

So it's working, but as I have only one web application, by default it takes this one but imagine if I have some web applications, how can I choose the one I need?

I made some searches but it's not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The association is made via the Proxy Group; the Proxy Group is tied to the Web Application. You can have one Proxy Group for each Web App, or share the same one for all Web Apps, or any combination there of.

Comment: But Can I choose my proxygroup no?
With this command: Get-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup -Identity, I just don't understand how to use it :/